# AVAudioSession requestRecordPermission with custom prompt?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, avaudiosession

I just installed the [Square Register](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/square-register-accept-credit/id335393788?mt=8) app on my iPhone 5S. When it first opened, it requested microphone access as expected, but what caught my eye was that it had a customized prompt explaining *why* it needed microphone access. I'm currently developing an app the requires microphone access and I'd like to be able to do this as well. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) for `requestRecordPermission` seems to suggest that there is no such option available. Did Apple give this developer special access to undocumented iOS 7 features, or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is... but for iOS7 and later...

in you app.plist add this key: `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` and your desired customized prompt. More details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW1

Comment: In iOS 6 they had deprecated the CLLocationManger.purpose property without any notes about why (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html). I figured they had just got rid of the capability altogether, but now I see that's also in the plist. Thanks again—good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

in Xcode 8 and iOS 10 you should manually add

> Privacy - Microphone Usage Description

to your plist file